# How to get website's logo and name by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, web-extension

I am working on a browser WebExtension, one feature of my extension is to get the icon image and name of the website which user is browsing.
I found some ways to get the icon, e.g

1. https://<some domain>/favicon.ico
2. link and metadata in header, such as `<meta property="og:image" content="<some image link>" />`, `<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<some image link>"`.

As for the website name, I can use

1. document.title
2. metadata in header, such as `<meta name="application-name" content="some name">`
3. the second level domain name

However, that is still not enough, I found the result is not satisfying  on quite a lot websites.

I am wondering is there some list of those heuristics or routines to cover most of the cases.

Or is there any advice or better approach to get the site's logo/icon and name?

Thank you